# What is the best way to select a minimum value from a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write an SQL statement (postgresql in this case) to assemble values from a table called "**subfield**" that are all related by a specific varfield_id.

Most of my the data coming from subfield do not repeat, with the exception of data with the tag of "c". The order of values with a tag of "c" are then defined by display_order which is an int.

My goal is to only select the content value for rows having the minimum value of display_order with tag of "c" (and meeting the other JOIN criteria). I've included my SQL below along with a sample of the output for one record_num specifically that may help clear things up.

```
SELECT 
r.record_num, a.content, q.content, c.display_order, c.content, d.content
FROM
db.subfield     a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
db.subfield     q
ON
  a.varfield_id = q.varfield_id and q.tag = 'q'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
db.subfield     c
ON
  a.varfield_id = c.varfield_id and c.tag = 'c'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
db.subfield     d
ON
  a.varfield_id = d.varfield_id and d.tag = 'd'
JOIN
db.record_metadata  r
ON
  a.record_id = r.id and r.record_type_code = 'b'
WHERE 
a.marc_tag = '100' and a.tag = 'a' and r.record_num = 2594119

--SAMPLE OF RETURNED DATA
--r.record_num; a.content;  q.content;      c.display_order;    c.content;      d.content;
--2594119;      "Name";     "(other Name)"; 2;                  "Name Title 2"; "YEAR-YEAR";
--2594119;      "Name";     "(other Name)"; 1;                  "Name Title 1"; "YEAR-YEAR";
```

Is there a simple way to only get back the row with the smallest c.display_order? I'm wanting to eventually run this query against a full table of subfield data, and will not be limiting to specific record numbers. In other words, I would like only one row returned per tag value of 'a' found in subfield, containing all other subfield values with non-repeating tag values, 'q' and 'd', and only the tag value 'c' with the smallest display_order.

Thanks to anyone willing to help out here!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.record_num, a.content, q.content
 , c.display_order, c.content, d.content
FROM db.subfield     a
LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield  q
    ON a.varfield_id = q.varfield_id AND q.tag = 'q'
LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield     c
     ON a.varfield_id = c.varfield_id AND c.tag = 'c'
     AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * FROM db.subfield nx
         WHERE nx.varfield_id = c.varfield_id   -- <<-- same
         AND nx.tag = c.tag                     -- <<-- same 
         AND nx.display_order < c.display_order -- <<--- different
         )
LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield     d
    ON a.varfield_id = d.varfield_id and d.tag = 'd'
JOIN db.record_metadata  r
    ON a.record_id = r.id and r.record_type_code = 'b'
WHERE a.marc_tag = '100' and a.tag = 'a'
and r.record_num = 2594119
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgresql 9.3 or later then you can use a [`LATERAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL). This is fairly similar to a `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery, but you can access columns from the outer query from within the subquery:

```
SELECT  r.record_num, a.content, q.content, c.display_order, c.content, d.content
FROM    db.subfield     a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield AS q
            ON a.varfield_id = q.varfield_id AND q.tag = 'q'
        LEFT JOIN LATERAL
        (   SELECT  c.display_order, c.content
            FROM    db.subfield AS c
            WHERE   a.varfield_id = c.varfield_id 
            AND     c.tag = 'c'
            ORDER BY c.display_order
        ) AS c ON TRUE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield AS d
            ON a.varfield_id = d.varfield_id AND d.tag = 'd'
        JOIN db.record_metadata AS r
            ON a.record_id = r.id AMD r.record_type_code = 'b'
WHERE   a.marc_tag = '100' 
AND     a.tag = 'a' 
AND     r.record_num = 2594119;
```

**[Simplified example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/146d1/4)**

The other option you have is to use [`DISTINCT ON ()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT  r.record_num, a.content, q.content, c.display_order, c.content, d.content
FROM    db.subfield     a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield AS q
            ON a.varfield_id = q.varfield_id AND q.tag = 'q'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  DISTINCT ON (c.varfield_id), c.varfield_id c.display_order, c.content
            FROM    db.subfield AS c
            WHERE   c.tag = 'c'
            ORDER BY c.varfield_id, c.display_order
        ) AS c 
            ON a.varfield_id = c.varfield_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN db.subfield AS d
            ON a.varfield_id = d.varfield_id AND d.tag = 'd'
        JOIN db.record_metadata AS r
            ON a.record_id = r.id AMD r.record_type_code = 'b'
WHERE   a.marc_tag = '100' 
AND     a.tag = 'a' 
AND     r.record_num = 2594119;
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/146d1/9)**